# How do I pull entered values from entry box made through a range

Tags: python, tkinter

I have to make 10 entry boxes and rather than do each one individually, I've done them like this:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    widthEntry = Entry(root, width=int(9.5), relief='solid')
    widthEntry.grid(row=i+7, column=2, ipady=2)
```

so how do I pull the value entered into, for example, entry box 7 so that I can use that value in calculations?
I'm using Python and Tkinter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list to contain the `Entry` instances.

```py
entries = []
for i in range(0,10):
    widthEntry = Entry(root, width=int(9.5), relief='solid')
    widthEntry.grid(row=i+7, column=2, ipady=2)
    entries.append(widthEntry)
```

Get the 7th entry box:

```py
entries[6].get()
```